# Uncontrolled range input renders slowly even when properly throttled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

More just looking for general guidelines. Cos I don't know where to look right now.

I have an uncontrolled `input[type=range]` slider that runs very slow when there are a lot of steps (works fine with fewer steps). I tried to throttle it, but it didn't really speed it up.

[image]

I had the component printing out the props that it received and it showed that the `onChange` function was properly throttled. But somehow the component is not updating in each throttled step. It only renders drag start and drag end and it looks stuck in the middle of dragging.

```
function SliderInput(props){
    console.log(props.value) 
    //this is logging properly(3.3, 3.25, 2, 1.1), but the middle are not rendered, thumb only changes at drag start and drag finish
    
    const throttledCallback = useCallback(throttle((value) => props.onChange(value), 100), []);
    
    return(
        <input type="range" min={props.min} max={props.max} step={props.step} value={props.value} onChange={ (e) => throttledCallback(Number(e.target.value)) } />
    )
}
```

The `props.onChange` function is more complicated than normal, but the `console.log` in the `SliderInput` shows that the component is receiving each step in time, so it shouldn't be an issue.

There's a possibility with parent component being complicated. But I tested and the parent's not unnecessarily re-rendering either.

```
// logs on each prop update. Doesn't show anything.
Class Form Extends React.PureComponent{
    ...
    onChange(value){
        console.log(value)
        ...
    }
    ...

    ...
    render(){
        const formState = this.getFormState();
        console.log("re-rendering");//gets logged the same frequency as log in SliderInput
        ...
        return(
            ...
            <SliderInput value={formState.value} onChange={this.onChange} ...... />
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

And here's the log that I get (no unnecessary re-renders):

```
3.45 -- Form > onChange
re-rendering -- Form > render
3.45 -- SliderInput

3.4 -- Form > onChange
re-rendering -- Form > render //but the thumb is stuck even it says it's re-rendering.
3.4 -- SliderInput

2.85 -- Form > onChange
re-rendering -- Form > render
2.85 -- SliderInput

2.6 -- Form > onChange
re-rendering -- Form > render
2.6 -- SliderInput

2.25 -- Form > onChange
re-rendering -- Form > render
2.25 -- SliderInput
```

As demonstrated, the slider thumb only renders the 3.45 and 2.25 values. Looks stuck on all middle values.

Comment: Actually it's controlled lol. Just nested. But it's not stored in react state. `formState` is actually some data in Unity... Not important tho...

Comment: You may use https://material-ui.com/components/slider/ it also has step functionality maybe it works.

Comment: @ChetanJain Thanks for the comment. But I need some custom functionalities with this slider so third-party isn't the first thing I would go for.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what tripped up the original implementation, but I decided instead of calling `onChange` on every input, I only call it on `mouseup`. Like an uncontrolled input calling `onChange` on `blur`...

I am displaying a custom tooltip over the thumb, so I so have to keep a local value just for the tooltip.

It's still not ideal though, since changes are not reflected elsewhere in the app until the user releases the slider. So still waiting for answers.

```
function SliderInput(props) {
    //local copy
    const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState(props.value)
    
    const position = ////some calculation using localValue about where the tooltip should be
    return(
        <div>
            <input min={props.min} max={props.max} step={props.step} defaultValue={props.value}
                onChange={(e) => setLocalValue(Number(e.target.value))}
                onMouseUp={(e) => props.onChange(Number(e.target.value))}
            />
            <output style={{left: `${position}px`}}>
                {localValue}
            </output>   
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with how you update the state.
The following version made with functional components only works.

## Note I use throttle from lodash.

```
import { FC, useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import _, { throttle } from 'lodash'
function SliderInput(props: { value: number; onChange: (x: number) => void }) {
    console.log(props.value)
    //this is logging properly(3.3, 3.25, 2, 1.1), but the middle are not rendered, thumb only changes at drag start and drag finish
    const throttledCallback = useCallback(throttle((value) => props.onChange(value), 100), []);

    return (
        <input type="range" min={1} max={2} step={0.1} value={props.value} onChange={(e) => throttledCallback(Number(e.target.value))} />
    )
}


function Form() {
    const [state, setstate] = useState(1)

    return (
        <>
        <SliderInput value={state} onChange={(x) => {
            console.log({ x })
            setstate(x)
        }} />
        <div>{state}</div>
        </>
    )
}



const Prototype: FC = () => (
    <Form />
)


export default Prototype
```